# Migration of data from SQL/Oracle to Cassandra using Pentaho

Tags: mysql, oracle, cassandra, pentaho, migrate

I want to migrate data from Oracle/MySQL to Cassandra by using Pentaho. Is there anyone who completed this task?

I want to know complete way how to migrate the data and what are the prerequisite for moving the data?

Answer (score 0):

It very much depend on the level of data reorganization planned.

If your goal is just to change the underlying DBMS, and can copy/paste the tables, you have a `Wizard` (Menu `Tools`) called `Copy Tables` (plural), which will ask you the input and output connection and create all what is needed (SQL create script, one Transformation per table, one job to execute the set of transformations).

It won't work in your case because Cassandra is not a sql database. However, it will give you a skeleton, in which you'll have to replace all the `Output table`s with a `Cassandra output`, which provides you in one click the CQL to execute before inserting rows.

But that is theory. Not because of the technicalities, but because such a migration requires a change the data model which is difficult to guess if you are not very familiar with the business.

So, start migrating the table with the least foreign keys, and ask feedback to your boss/client. Then move to the next table, and so on. Always choose a table with no foreign key that was not yet moved, and make a check (record count) and ask feedback to the users. You'll soon be asked for a change in the data structure.

Also note that if the Oracle/MySQL databases are in production, the data changes every day. So, don't throw away your ETL, but include them in a single `Job`, so that you can reload fresh data on a simple click.